# Can not set up ruby and rails properly because of my path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, rvm

Trying to bundle a rails project my company has set up for me, just installed everything onto a new computer.  But keep running into this error:

> Warning! PATH is not properly set up,
>   '/Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin' is not at first place,
>            usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
>            it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
>            to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.0'.

Doing which -a ruby gives me this:

> /Users/Name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby

And

> /usr/bin/ruby

And when I echo my $PATH I get this:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby2.1.0/bin:/Users/Name/.rvm/gems/ruby2.1.0@global/bin:/Users/Name/.rvm/rubies/ruby2.1.0/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Name/.rvm/bin

Could anyone help me figure this issue out?  I've looked online quite a bit and have yet to find a walkthrough or real in-depth explanation on how to fix this issue.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: somewhere in your **.bash...* init files the PATH is changed o become `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin` on the first place, please see them

Comment: @maijoa My path apparently applied multiple versions of itself to the my $PATH variable.  Therefore /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin became:  /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin
Needless to say I had to go in and remove the multiple versions.
Very strange.  Unable, and Unwilling to replicate this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553043/path-is-not-properly-set-up/41091379#41091379) to a similar question. You need to go through your terminal's config files (.bash_profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, etc).

Replace this line: `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`
With this line: `export PATH="$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`

To make sure the RVM code is always at the start of $PATH