# $PATH is not properly set up

Tags: ruby, version-control, rvm, homebrew

I just ran 'rvm get stable' to be given the below error;

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/jamesbkemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2.1'.
```

Previous to running 'rvm get stable' I ran 'brew upgrade ruby' to Ruby 2.2.2.

'echo $PATH' returns the below:

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin:/Users/user/.rvm/bin
```

I don't understand what the issue is here or why when i run 'ruby -v' it returns 'ruby 2.2.1p85'.

Running 'rvm list' returns the below, as well as the same PATH error message detailed above;

```
ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried running `rvm reset`?

Comment: No, I've done nothing other than the above. Is this the command I should run once I've updated a newer version of Ruby (via Homebrew)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "Warning! PATH is not properly set up" when doing rvm use 2.0.0 --default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276701/getting-warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-when-doing-rvm-use-2-0-0-defaul)

Comment: That question's answers has not solved the issues I have. I have not run 'rvm use ruby-2.2.1' as I just brew installed Ruby 2.2.2 and want to run that.

Comment: Thats not was he meant. You should run `rvm use ruby-2.2.2` because ruby-2.2.1 is still selected. This should change the PATH and those eliminate the warning.

Comment: Essentially a lack of a clear understanding of the difference between RVM and Homebrew has lead to my confusion here. 'rvm use ruby-2.2.2' has my system now using the most recent version. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Put RVM code at the start of $PATH

I just had the same problem. I went to terminal and entered `subl ~/` which opens up your home folder on Sublime Text (or you can use another text editor).

I then clicked on every file starting with `.`, e.g. `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.mkshrc`, `.zshrc`

Whenever I saw this line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

I changed it to this:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

That way, the RVM code is at the start of `$PATH`. Then I quit Terminal and started it up again to make sure those config files were loaded.